# How to make the text of a variable bold in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have a scenario where I would like to bold the text which is present inside a variable in Tkinter.

The code is as follows:

```
best_batsmen = dataset.loc[dataset.loc[dataset['Innings']>=15,'Average'].idxmax(),'Names']
message = ("The best Batsman of the Tournament could possibly be: " + best_batsmen)
canvas_width = 500
canvas_height = 500
root = Toplevel()
root.geometry("700x600")
root.title("Best Batsman")
canvas = Canvas(root, width=canvas_width, height=canvas_height)
canvas.create_text(1, 10, anchor=W, text=message)
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("virat.jpeg"))
canvas.create_image(0, 20, anchor=NW, image=img)
canvas.image = img
canvas.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

In the above code, I would like to bold only the text present inside the best_batsmen variable using Tkinter. Can anyone please help me in figuring that out.

Comment: put text from `best_batsmen` as separated text on canvas and then you can use different font, color, etc.

Comment: @furas or can I edit `canvas.create_text(1, 10, anchor=W, text=message)` to `canvas.create_text(1, 10, anchor=W, text=message + best_batsman.font='bold'`. Will this work?

Comment: You can separate the message into two labels and put them inside a frame, then use create_window to add the frame into the canvas.

Comment: did you try it ? you can't use `.font` (with dot). You may use only `, font='bold` but this will change all message to bold, not only `best_batsman`.

Comment: @furas, yes you were right!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use second `create_text` to put only text `best_batsman` with `font='bold'`

```
canvas.create_text(1, 10, anchor='w', text=message)
canvas.create_text(380, 10, anchor='w', text=best_batsmen, font='bold')
```

but you have to manually calculate `x` position for `best_batsmen` (ie. `380`)

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

best_batsmen = "James Bond"
message = "The best Batsman of the Tournament could possibly be: "

canvas_width = 500
canvas_height = 500

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=canvas_width, height=canvas_height)
canvas.pack()

canvas.create_text(1, 10, anchor='w', text=message)
canvas.create_text(380, 10, anchor='w', text=best_batsmen, font='bold')

img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("virat.jpeg"))
canvas.create_image(0, 20, anchor='nw', image=img)
#canvas.image = img

root.mainloop()
```

Eventually you can try to calculate position with `tkinter.font.Font().measure()`

```
import tkinter.font as tkfont

#width = tkfont.Font(family='arial', size=20, weight='normal').measure(message)
width = tkfont.Font().measure(message)
canvas.create_text(width, 10, anchor='w', text=best_batsmen, font='bold')
```

---

If you put text above image so you don't need text with transparent background then you can put `Frame` using `pack()` and put two `Labels` inside `Frame` using `pack(side='left')`

```
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

tk.Label(frame, text=message).pack(side='left')
tk.Label(frame, text=best_batsmen, font='bold').pack(side='left')
```

This way you don't have to calculate `x` position for `best_batsmen`

And you can put image in position `(0, 0)`

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

best_batsmen = "James Bond"
message = "The best Batsman of the Tournament could possibly be: "

canvas_width = 500
canvas_height = 500

root = tk.Tk()

frame = tk.Frame(root)

tk.Label(frame, text=message).pack(side='left')
tk.Label(frame, text=best_batsmen, font='bold').pack(side='left')
frame.pack()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=canvas_width, height=canvas_height)
canvas.pack()

img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("virat.jpeg"))
canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor='nw', image=img)
#canvas.image = img

root.mainloop()
```

Or you can use `create_window(..., window=frame)` to put it on canvas. You have to do it after you create `Canvas`.

```
frame = tk.Frame(root)
canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=frame, anchor='nw')

tk.Label(frame, text=message).pack(side='left')
tk.Label(frame, text=best_batsmen, font='bold').pack(side='left')
```

If you would like to put on image - not above - the you would have to use `creat_window` after `create_image`. But widgets (`Frame`, 'Label', etc.) can't have transparent background.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkinter.font as tkfont

best_batsmen = "James Bond"
message = "The best Batsman of the Tournament could possibly be: "

canvas_width = 500
canvas_height = 500

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=canvas_width, height=canvas_height)
canvas.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(root)
canvas.create_window(1, 0, window=frame, anchor='nw')

tk.Label(frame, text=message).pack(side='left')
tk.Label(frame, text=best_batsmen, font='bold').pack(side='left')

img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("virat.jpeg"))
canvas.create_image(0, 20, anchor='nw', image=img)
#canvas.image = img

root.mainloop()
```

---

Instead of `Frame` with `Labels` you could use `Text` with tags with assigned colors and weights.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a text on the canvas and edit its font styles.

```
canvas.create_text(1, 10, font=('arial', 20, BOLD), text='your text here')
```

You would have to import the style from tkinter fonts for this.

```
from tkinter.font import BOLD
```

Answer (score 0):

You can separate the message into 2 parts:

```
best_batsmen = 'Virat Kohli'
message = 'The best Batsman of the Tournament could possibly be: '
```

Then draw the first part as usual:

```
msg = canvas.create_text(1, 10, text=message, anchor=W)
```

Use the returned item ID `msg` to get the bounding box and font for the `message`:

```
bbox = canvas.bbox(msg) # get the message bounding box
# import tkinter.font as tkfont
font = tkfont.Font(font=canvas.itemcget(msg, 'font')) # get the message font
```

Then set the weight of the font to 'bold' and draw the second part at the end of the first part using bold style:

```
font['weight'] = 'bold' # change font weight to bold
# show best_batsmen at the end of the message with bold style
canvas.create_text(bbox[2], bbox[1], text=best_batsmen, font=font, anchor=NW)
```

Comment: What do you mean "It isn't working"? Error? Or not what you expect?  I have tested the code and it is working.

Comment: It isn't displaying any text on the screen.